# What is the Jetty 8 Continuations default timeout period?

Tags: timeout, jetty, continuations

I've been working with [Jetty's Continuations API](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Continuations#Suspending_a_Request) and just figured out a very frustrating bug (* **at least I think this was the reason***).

If I had read more closely, I would have seen this:

> The timeout should be set before the suspend, by a call to
>   continuation.setTimeout(long); if no timeout is set, then the default
>   period is used.

So in my code, I was simply suspending a continuation without setting a timeout. When I read this in the documentation...

> A timeout of <=0 means the continuation will never expire.

... and then tried setting the timeout to something negative, things started working (* **at least it seems so** *).

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out what the "default period" is for a timeout. Where can I find this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I figured this out while stepping through the debugger... the default time period is 30 seconds. I found the source code...

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/eclipse/jetty/aggregate/jetty-all/8.0.4.v20111024/jetty-all-8.0.4.v20111024-sources.jar!/org/eclipse/jetty/continuation/FauxContinuation.java?format=ok

... and it seems like this `FauxContinuation` implementation of a `Continuation` was being constructed and the timeout is initialized to 30 seconds.

```
private long _timeoutMs = 30000;
```

Comment: yes, default timeout on continuations is 30s, and it might be easier to go straight to the source instead of rooting around jar services like that: http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/